# Can not load fancybox from function, but it works outside of a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to load a fancybox from a click even within a function. It will work outside of a javascript function but will not work within a function.

Example:
This works on page load and opens a fancybox right away:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    autoSize: false,
    href: '/manager/users/edit/1',
    type: 'iframe' 
});
```

If I listen for an click event it then does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.edit_user').click( function() { 
        $.fancybox.open({
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            autoSize: false,
            href: '/manager/users/edit/1',
            type: 'iframe' 
            });
    });
});
```

Onclick that fails and returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are those 2 examples from the same page or different pages?

Comment: Yes, same exact placement on the page. If I replace the first example with the 2nd example then I get the Error. First example works fine without the click even though.

Comment: tis very odd... not sure why but see if my answer works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
    $(document).on('click', '.edit_user', function() { 
        $.fancybox.open({
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            autoSize: false,
            href: '/manager/users/edit/1',
            type: 'iframe' 
            });
    });
```

or depending on your version of jquery

```
    $('.edit_user').live('click', function() { 
        $.fancybox.open({
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            autoSize: false,
            href: '/manager/users/edit/1',
            type: 'iframe' 
            });
    });
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined

Comment: For some reason fanxybox seems to be hidden for my functions... It is very odd.

Comment: does your first example work with a document.ready block or without?

Comment: If I wrap the first example in document.ready it fails as well

Comment: Negative If I take out the document.ready and just leave the click function I still receive the error. Document.ready was just an attempt to resolve it.

Comment: Still the same -- worst case I can post userID back the same page and load modal on page load, but seems sloppy

Comment: Neither worked for me -- something must be conflicting I am just going to take another route. This is taking to much time, appreciate the help though

Comment: yeah has to be something else going on i cant see.. np

Answer (score 0):

seems like difference of jquery library versions, after you quoted i tried locally to implement it. it worked for me on click event. this is the code what i tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickme").click(function() {
                    $.fancybox.open({
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    autoSize: false,
                    href: 'index.html',
                    type: 'iframe' 
                });
            });
        });
```

Complete code what i tried out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox Tryout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }

        body {
            max-width: 700px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>fancyBox <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clickme">click</a></h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickme").click(function() {
                    $.fancybox.open({
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    autoSize: false,
                    href: 'index.php',
                    type: 'iframe' 
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of jquery were you using for that?

Comment: Yea that is exactly what I am doing, but on a class not and ID which should not make a difference. It should be working there must be a conflict somehwhere else in my code. I am taking another route. Thanks for your help.